# Understanding outdated Libgdx code

Tags: android, libgdx, legacy

Am trying to understand the following piece of code. According to the author,
he is trying to reset the camera position based on the gutter width and height. By gutter, I take it the author means the black bars on the screen.
The problem is that I cant seem to find the methods
setViewport(int,int,boolean) and getGutterWidth() and getGutterHeight() on the Stage class. I think this code was written with an outdated Libgdx API. What am looking for is the equivalent code that will perform the same task as this outdated code:

```
private Stage stage;

public void resize(int width, int height){
stage.setViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT, true);
stage.getCamera().translate(-stage.getGutterWidth(),
-stage.getGutterHeight(), 0);}
```

Answer (score 1):

These black bars are now handled by the viewport classes, see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports for a overview and short description.

In our case I would suggest a FitViewport:

```
Viewport viewport = FitViewport(MyGame.WIDTH, MyGame.HEIGHT, camera);
Stage stage = new Stage(viewport);
```

Comment: @i_o LibGDX is open-source - so you could also see the `Viewport.java` (or any other LibGDX) source file [on github](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.java) as well.